# What does Majestic.com 'Trust Flow' number mean?

Tags: seo, google

My site's 'trust flow' is currently 7 and I was wondering what does that mean? Can I tell from this whether I have a Penguin penalty for bad backlinks and what else does it mean? (I will ask a separate question on how to improve this score). Thank you.

Comment: It means absolutely nothing. You shouldn't give it another second of thought. If you want to know how to improve your score ask them as only they know. And it does not tell whether you have a penguin penalty. There is no way to officially check that.

Comment: _Trust Flow - Trust Flow is one of the Majestic Flow Metrics, which is weighted by the number of clicks from a seed set of trusted sites to a given URL, or Domain._ **Technobabble excreted to make it sound like something. Explained by further nebulous verbiage:** _Flow Metrics - Flow Metrics are scores assigned to websites and URLs by algorithms run on Majestic servers during the build of an index. Flow Metrics are expressed as numbers between 0 and 100, the higher the number, the stronger the signal._ **Signal?** Basically, Majestic failed as a search engine and are trying to monetize BOM.

Comment: Pay attention to Google and Bing and nothing else. There are a cr@pl0@d of online SEO websites and damn near all of them are complete junk designed to take your money. Nothing more. You do not need them or should worry about what any of them have to say. You will have more hair in your old age that way. (hopefully)

Answer (score 2):

From https://blog.majestic.com/development/flow-metrics/

> ### Trust Flow
>
> We start with a large list on manually reviewed URLs. These have a crowd-sourced level of trust but by no means include all the trusted sites on the web. It turns out, though, that trustworthy sites tend to link to trustworthy neighbours. Those neighbours also tend to link to trustworthy neighbours themselves. In fact – after lots of iterations – those outside the circle of trust are put in the cold.  So Trust Flow, like Citation Flow passes THROUGH urls like sound passes through walls – with awesome effects.

It sounds to me like they have implemented a version of Google's PageRank algorithm.   However, for this metric all the weight starts out in a set of manually reviewed "trusted sites".    Then they let the link juice flow through all the links they found when crawling the web.